# Find user by name and surname in USER collection

Tags: laravel, collections

This is my code:

```
public function search_clients($names){
    $user = Auth::user();

    $all_clients = $user->clients; // Retrieve object of all clients of user
         
    $names = ["Pera","Peric"]; // Pera - name, Peric - surname

    $collect = collect($all_clients);

    $klijenti = $collect->filter(function($query) use ($names){
      $query->whereIn('name', $names);
      $query->orWhere(function($query) use ($names) {
          $query->whereIn('surname', $names);
      });
      return $query;
    });
  return $klijenti;
 }
```

I want to search in object for name and surname and return it. Like if I have 100 users in $all_clients, i want to return only users name or surname LIKE "PERA" or "PERIC".

Currently it is returning everyone.

Comment: you only want to return the user objects that have those values or you only want to return those strings?

Comment: Return user object that have those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to define a search scope on the Client model

```php
class Client extends Model
{
    public function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm)
    {
        $query->where("name", "ilike", "%$searchTerm%")
            ->orWhere("surname", "ilike", "%$searchTerm%");
    }

    //rest of the code
}
```

Then in the controller method you can use the scope

```php
public function search_clients($names)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $all_clients = $user->clients()->search($names)->get();

    return $all_clients;
}
```

Comment: After few modifications it works. Thank you man, if we meet sometime, you have beer from me! :)